# VS2010 - Issue hitting break points when changing OS language

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have a web application that I am trying to test localization on.  When the language of Windows 7 is set to English my breakpoints get hit with no issue.  If the language is changed to French then none of the same breakpoints are being hit when it is run in debug mode.

Was wondering if anyone had gone through this issue before.  Is this occurring because folder name changes happen in different languages of Windows 7 or is it some bug within Visual Studio 2010?  Thanks for the help.

[EDIT] I just did a test case where I created a new web site in the French language version of Windows and the breakpoint was being hit properly in this but not in my actual application.  I have also tried Attaching the debugger to the application but this did not have any effect either.

Comment: Is it possible the code your breakpoint is on is not executed when the language is French?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint somewhere else - preferably somewhere you absolutely know is being executed?

Comment: I don't believe this is the case because I set a couple breakpoints on the page_load event for a variety of pages and they were not triggered.  I know it is possible to hit breakpoints when the language is French but something has to be changing for all of my breakpoints to fail while running under French.